# Django registration template doesn't load form when entered

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have a problem with my Django registration template. To register I'm using a Django-auth system. Theoretically it works, because whenever I enter my registration site, it loads the template, but it only shows my registration button. When I click it, the page reload and the form shows up. I assume it's something about POST method but I can't figure it out to load form right away, after redirect.

This is my views.py:

```
class RegisterView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'register/register.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, })
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Here is picture of my register.html template, somehow I couldn't paste it as a code:
[image: the register.html template]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're issue here is that you're returning `return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, })` this regardless of whether the registration was successful or not. Are you seeing a new user in your DB?

Anyway, here is how I would do it using class based views (it saves you a lot of extra code)

forms.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("email", "username")
```

views.py

```py
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm


class SignupPageView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login") # this refers to a name in urls.py
    template_name = "account/signup.html"
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("/signup", SignupPageView.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path("/login", YourLoginViewHere.as_view(), name="login"),
]
```

Also check out django-allauth. It's a very nifty package for user auth/login/registration.

Comment: Thanks, now that looks so simple :) Problem solved. Thank you also for the tips. Cheers